# How to add custom shortcode button in product page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to add custom button down to add to cart in product page that triggers shortcode for popup
please
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfpUt.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart_button_func' );
/*
 * Content below "Add to cart" Button.
 */
function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {

        // Echo content.
        echo 'Add your code here';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function buttonElement( $atts, $content = null) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'link' => ''
    ), $atts ) );
    return'<a href="'.$link.'">$content</a>';
};
add_shortcode('button', 'buttonElement');
```

So now you have to call the shorcode as below:

```
[button link"add__your__button__link" ]Here is button text[/button]
```